# Software deployment to Vista and Win7

Tags: windows-server-2003, group-policy, deployment

How we can deploy software using GPO from Server 2003 to Vista or Win7?

Comment: Are you having a specific problem, or just asking how to deploy software via Group Policy in general?

My Active Directory is still on Server 2003 and nothing has changed in Windows Vista & 7 with regards to software deployment, and I can say from personal experience it works no differently than deploying to XP did (and the software deployed works as expected).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft KB #816102: "[How to use Group Policy to remotely install software in Windows Server 2003](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816102)"

Comment: its ok, i think it was a compatibility problem, is there any way to push the software to be installed completely at first log in.

Comment: Yes, assign it to a computer object so that it's installed no matter who uses it. You can also assign it to a user object. I prefer assigning to computer objects.

Comment: If you're having problems with certain software, you can always apply a WMI filter to stop it being applied to certain operating systems. Also pretty effective in my experience :)

Comment: Remember, there is a difference between "assigning" software and "publishing" software. You can only assign software packages to computer objects, you can publish or assign software packages to user objects. Read up on the difference as I'd be guilty of unnecessary redundancy if I wrote it all out here.

Comment: i tried it and it work great thanks, ben if you can give me a reference about wmi ?

Comment: Just came across this post, and would like to say thanks to Wesley. I never knew that deploy software, need to assign the .msi package in Computer section, and then deploy it in the user section. No wonder my Group Policy Deployment never seem to work before. thank you.